# How to update phpunit installed with symfony3

Tags: php, phpunit, symfony

I want to start unit testing my symfony 3 application with the latest version of phpunit. I followed [this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html#functional-tests) tutorial. but when i runed this command

> phpunit -c

According to the official site https://phpunit.de/ the installed version of php unit  is not the latest version (!= 5.6):

```
PHPUnit 4.8.17 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
```

the class test is :

class CalculatorTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase

```
{
    public function testAdd()
    {
        $calc = new Calculator();
        $result = $calc->add(30, 12);

        // assert that your calculator added the numbers correctly!
        $this->assertEquals(42, $result);
    }
}
```

I don't know that the framework use a bundle to import the **PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase** class or use the phpunit installed on my pc ?
And How can i update the phpunit version ?

Comment: my php version is : 5.6.31

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` (and other `PHPUnit_*` code) will be imported from PHPUnit that are you executed. 
Symfony is not require specific version of PHPUnit. For example, you can install the test framework as project (dev-)dependency and run it directly:

```
vendor/bin/phpunit -c app/
```

[But](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html#the-phpunit-testing-framework)

> it's recommended to use the latest stable PHPUnit version, installed as PHAR.

If your PHPUnit version doesn't support your version of PHP, obviously you can use an older version of PHPUnit or update the platform.

Comment: +1
thanks, i updated my phpunit version to 5.6.4 and symfony 3 uses the phpUnit_framework_test_case from the program installed on my pc